# Horizontal Div Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm quite new to Jquery, I'm trying to implement horizontal scrolling on a div using the scrollLeft property, I'm not getting any error messages and nothing seems to be working, could someone explain why? Thanks in advance
this is my code:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready (function(){
            var pos  = $("#container").scrollLeft();
            $(".prev").click(function(){
                $("#container").animate({
                    scrollLeft: pos - 200;
                });
            }); 
        });
    
        
        
  </script>
```

```css
<style>
        #container{
            max-width: 938px;
            height: 500px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            overflow: scroll;
            /*display: table;*/
        }
        .picsdiv{
            display: table-cell;
            min-width: 286px;
            padding-right: 80px;
            height: 508px;
            border: 2px solid pink;
            
        }
        
        .prev, .next {
          cursor: pointer;
          position: absolute;
          top: 250px;
          width: auto;
          margin-top: -22px;
          padding: 16px;
          color: white;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 18px;
          transition: 0.6s ease;
          border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            border: 2px solid pink;
        }

        .next {
          right: 170px;
          border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        }
        .prev{
            left: 170px;
        }

        .prev:hover, .next:hover {
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        }
    </style>
```

```html
  
<body>
   <div id="container">
       <div class="picsdiv">
       
       </div>
       <div class="picsdiv">
       
       </div>
       <div class="picsdiv">
       
       </div>
       <div class="picsdiv">
       
       </div>
       <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
    </div> 
    
</body>
```

Comment: you have an syntax error `scrollLeft: pos - 200;` should not end with a semicolon

Comment: &Pato Salazar, I've gotten rid of it, it still doesn't work

Comment: tell me exactly what are you doing to test this code... are you scrolling first and then click previous to make it go back... or are you clicking prev button immediately??

Comment: scrolling first, and then clicking to make it go back.

Comment: so in the code you are showing.. why are you adding two different version of jQuery?

Comment: the first block of code is your `.js` file?? I think you are including your jQuery and script file wrong.

Comment: that was just a mistake when I was entering the code on Stackiverflow, I'm only referring to Jquery once as shown in the first script block. I've also edited the question and removed the 2nd reference

Comment: Just used a separate script tag to refer to the library and another one for the actual Jquery code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a seperate script tag for the Jquery code and used the first one to only refer to the library and it now works. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2):

take out the semi-colon on this line and it should work

```
scrollLeft: pos - 200;
```

Comment: it's still not working, actually already tried that before, it's weird cause my debugger isn't even giving me any error messages

Comment: yeah I didn't notice the script tags because I put it into jsfiddle

Comment: still don't have it working? did you fix the script tags?

Answer (score 0):

firstly you must close script tag that include jquery file and also open another script tag for your jquery code

Answer (score 0):

You have done 2 mistakes in your code:

1. **scrollLeft: pos - 200;** should be like **scrollLeft: (pos - 200)**, because you are passing an object as parameter
2. Write two `<script>` tags, one for jQuery, like below

   `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javacsript"></script>`

And another for your custom java-script

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready (function(){
        var pos  = $("#container").scrollLeft();
        $(".prev").click(function(){
            $("#container").animate({
                scrollLeft: (pos - 200)
            });
        }); 
    });
```

Because you can not write code inside  element if you are using ths element as external reference.

Here is your complete running code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>    
    #container{
    max-width: 938px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
    /*display: table;*/
    }
    .picsdiv{
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 286px;
    padding-right: 80px;
    height: 508px;
    border: 2px solid pink;
    }
    .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border: 2px solid pink;
    }
    .next {
    right: 170px;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }
    .prev{
    left: 170px;
    }
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="picsdiv">
        </div>
        <div class="picsdiv">
        </div>
        <div class="picsdiv">
        </div>
        <div class="picsdiv">
        </div>
        <a class="prev">&lt;</a>
        <a class="next">&gt;</a>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready (function(){
            var pos  = $("#container").scrollLeft();
            $(".prev").click(function(){
                $("#container").animate({
                    scrollLeft: (pos - 200)
                });
            }); 
        });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed some typos.